# Glassfish 4 cannot start with jdk1.7.0_51

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-4

I have updated the server the to JDK 1.7.0-51. But when i try to start the domain1 in glassfish, the console show me

```
JVM failed to start: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java" (in directory "/home/glassfish/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config"): error=13, Permiso denegado
```

When i try with my other installed versión [jdk 1.7.0_40] there are no problem

O.S: Oracle Linux

Glassfish 4.0

JDK: 1.7.0_51

Any idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: The problem was the jdk, my final action was upgrade the jdk to the last version

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, I use Fadora 20 for the development. When I installed Java version 1.7. I made configuration in my *home_directory/.bashrc* file, Then I made global configuration by editing */etc/bashrc*.

Later on when I updated my Java to 1.8, I made changes to global file, that is /etc/bashrd but I forgot to update my home_dir/.bashrc, so the old configuration of Java 1.7 was being overridden.

So check your JAVA_HOME path by "*export $JAVA_HOME*" it will tell you the path of Java Home.
I solved my problem by deleting local home_dir/.bashrc that was overriding my configuration!

I guess it will help!